# When and who calls the anonymous function we passed as argrument to Promise constructor?

Tags: javascript, promise, function-call

I'm learning *Promise* in JavaScript and just wonder how does it work behind the scenes?

As you see in the example there is only an anonymous function we pass to Promise constructor and no calling in the reminder of code.

If there wasn't any `.this` was it sitll being called and changed the state and value of `myPromise` object?

```js
let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
  let x = 0;

  if (x == 0) {
    myResolve("OK");
  } else {
    myReject("Error");
  }
});

myPromise.then(
  function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: TL;DR: the `Promise` constructor calls the function you pass to it, and it passes the `resolve` and `reject` functions to it when doing so.